# Compiler errors while trying to make a pop up

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors

I'm trying to make a pop up with `javax.swing` and I keep getting bugs of "object cannot be resolved to a type", but I'm not sure what type I need to use.

The problem area is:

```
((java.lang.object) cloesButton).MatteBorder
```

```
Jbutton cloesButton = new JButton();
((java.lang.object) cloesButton).MatteBorder(new Insets(1, 4, 1, 4));
cloesButton.setFocusable(false);
frame.add(cloesButton, constraints);
constraints.gridx = 0;
constraints.gridy++;
constraints.weightx = 1.0f;
constraints.weighty = 1.0f;
constraints.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
```

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Note that the first line of the code snippet above would also not compile, as there is no `Jbutton` in the Swing API (worng case of 2nd letter). So either you are misreading the place of the error, or the above code is **not** what is being used. An MRE / SSCCE, ***copy / pasted from the IDE*** should resolve matters.

Answer (score 2):

In that line, you're trying to cast cloesButton to be a java.lang.object, and then call the method MatteBorder on the resulting casted object.

There are two problems.  The first is that you're trying to cast it to something that doesn't exist, which is the error you're getting.  There is no class named java.lang.object.  There is one named java.lang.Object (capital O) but that isn't what you want, either.

Once you fix that, you'll get a new error that java.lang.Object does not have a method named MatteBorder.  JButton does not, either.  I know this only because a method would start with a lowercase letter, and I trust the writers of JButton to have followed that convention.

This might help:  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-set-color-to-matteborder-in-java